# Interpreting regression coefficients in weighted linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, weighted-regression

I have a dataset where I'm doing Multiple Linear Regression. Examining the residuals vs fitted plot, it was seen to exhibits heteroskedasticity. As an antidote, I am doing Weighed Least Squares Regression. Since a weight will be used, would that change the interpretation of the regression coefficients?

Would the interpretation of the coefficients still be *"the mean change in the response variable for one unit of change in the predictor variable while holding other predictors in the model constant."* ?

Comment: That’s the interpretation regardless of the error term. Weighted least squares just helps you with inferences on the parameter estimates.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that it makes std. error reliable after heteroskedasticity made it unreliable. But since adding a weight is kind of transforming the predictor variables by diving them by a value, I was wondering if it'll change the interpretation of the coefficients and hence the question. For other transforms, like log transformation, the interpretation of the coefficient changes.

Comment: The parameter estimates are the partial derivatives of your regression equation, whether you estimates by OLS or WLS.